# How to draw elliptical sector with Bresenham's algorithm?

Tags: math, graphics, geometry, ellipse, bresenham

How can I draw filled elliptical sector using Bresenham's algorithm and bitmap object with DrawPixel method?

I have written method for drawing ellipse, but this method uses symmetry and passes only first quadrant. This algorithm is not situable for sectors. Of course, I can write 8 cycles, but I think it's not the most elegant solution of the task.

Comment: You should indicate how your sector is parametrized. Compare e.g. [java.awt.geom.Arc.Double](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Arc2D.Double.html#Double-double-double-double-double-double-double-int-) with [SVG elliptic arc](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#PathDataEllipticalArcCommands) to get an idea of different parametrizations.

Comment: Bresenham is not a good way for this (unless you are bounded to integer math)

Comment: My sector is parameterized like java.awt.geom.Arc.Double. And I am bound to integer math.

Comment: @NikolaiPaukov such parametrization involves floating or fixed point for angles.... Integer style uses usually cutting lines like in GDI ... so the ellipse is axis aligned? with known center, a,b and 2 angles ?  And the angles are floats or integers and in what units ?

Comment: Yeah, the elliipse is axis aligned and angles are integers in degrees.

Comment: @NikolaiPaukov how do you compute cos and sin on integers (use floating for it, have integer fixed point LUT and in what range, or other ... )?  Also which angles it is (in scaled to circle space or real angle)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On integer math the usual parametrization is by using limiting lines (in CW or CCW direction) instead of your angles. So if you can convert those angles to such (you need `sin,cos` for that but just once)  then you can use integer math based rendering for this. As I mentioned in the comment bresenham is not a good approach for a sector of ellipse as you would need to compute the internal iterators and counters state for the start point of interpolation and also it will give you just the circumference points instead of filled shape.

There are many approaches out there for this here a simple one:

1. **convert ellipse to circle**

   simply by rescaling the smaller radius axis
2. **loop through bbox of such circle**

   simple 2 nested `for` loops covering the outscribed square to our circle
3. **check if point inside circle**

   simply check if `x^2 + y^2 <= r^2` while the circle is centered by `(0,0)`
4. **check if point lies between edge lines**

   so it should be CW with one edge and CCW with the other. You can exploit the cross product for this (its z coordinate polarity will tell you if point is CW or CCW against the tested edge line)

   but this will work only up to 180 deg slices so you need also add some checking for the quadrants to avoid false negatives. But those are just few ifs on top of this.
5. **if all conditions are met conver the point back to ellipse and render**

Here small C++ example of this:

```cpp
void elliptic_arc(int x0,int y0,int rx,int ry,int a0,int a1,DWORD c)    
    {
    // variables
    int  x, y, r,
        xx,yy,rr,
        xa,ya,xb,yb,                // a0,a1 edge points with radius r
        mx,my,cx,cy,sx,sy,i,a;
    // my Pixel access (you can ignore it and use your style of gfx access)
    int **Pixels=Main->pyx;         // Pixels[y][x]
    int   xs=Main->xs;              // resolution
    int   ys=Main->ys;
    // init variables
    r=rx; if (r<ry) r=ry; rr=r*r;   // r=max(rx,ry)
    mx=(rx<<10)/r;                  // scale from circle to ellipse (fixed point)
    my=(ry<<10)/r;
    xa=+double(r)*cos(double(a0)*M_PI/180.0);
    ya=+double(r)*sin(double(a0)*M_PI/180.0);
    xb=+double(r)*cos(double(a1)*M_PI/180.0);
    yb=+double(r)*sin(double(a1)*M_PI/180.0);
    // render
    for (y=-r,yy=y*y,cy=(y*my)>>10,sy=y0+cy;y<=+r;y++,yy=y*y,cy=(y*my)>>10,sy=y0+cy) if ((sy>=0)&&(sy<ys))
     for (x=-r,xx=x*x,cx=(x*mx)>>10,sx=x0+cx;x<=+r;x++,xx=x*x,cx=(x*mx)>>10,sx=x0+cx) if ((sx>=0)&&(sx<xs))
      if (xx+yy<=rr)                // inside circle
        {
        if ((cx>=0)&&(cy>=0)) a=  0;// actual quadrant
        if ((cx< 0)&&(cy>=0)) a= 90;
        if ((cx>=0)&&(cy< 0)) a=270;
        if ((cx< 0)&&(cy< 0)) a=180;
        if ((a   >=a0)||((cx*ya)-(cy*xa)<=0))           // x,y is above a0 in clockwise direction
         if ((a+90<=a1)||((cx*yb)-(cy*xb)>=0))
          Pixels[sy][sx]=c;
        }
    }
```

beware both angles must be in `<0,360>` range. My screen has y pointing down so if `a0<a1` it will be CW direction which matches the routione. If you use `a1<a0` then the range  will be skipped and the rest of ellipse will be rendered instead.

This approach uses `a0,a1` as real angles !!!

To avoid divides inside loop I used 10 bit fixed point scales instead.

You can simply divide this to 4 quadrants to avoid 4 if inside loops to improve performance.

`x,y` is point in circular scale centered by `(0,0)`

`cx,cy` is point in elliptic scale centered by `(0,0)`

`sx,sy` is point in elliptic scale translated to ellipse center position

**Beware** my pixel access is `Pixels[y][x]` but most apis use `Pixels[x][y]` so do not forget to change it to your api to avoid access violations or 90deg rotation of the result ...